# Error with PowerShell command for copying file to remote server with credential

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Copy-Item -ToSession $s C:\Programs\temp\test.txt -Destination C:\Programs\temp\test.txt
```

> Copy-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'ToSession'. At line:1 char:11
>
> - Copy-Item -ToSession $s C:\Programs\temp\test.txt -Destination C:\Programs\temp\ ...
> - ~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is noted in the change list of PoSh V5 [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-windows-powershell-50#a-name-bkmk-newcore-a-new-features-in-windows-powershell) and you tagged your question with V4 the simple answer is probably your version's `Copy-Item` cmdlet does not provide that parameter

> Copy-Item now lets you copy files or folders from one Windows
>   PowerShell session to another, meaning that you can copy files to
>   sessions that are connected to remote computers, (including computers
>   that are running Nano Server, and thus have no other interface). To
>   copy files, specify PSSession IDs as the value of the new -FromSession
>   and -ToSession parameters, and add –Path and –Destination to specify
>   origin path and destination, respectively. For example, Copy-Item
>   -Path c:\myFile.txt -ToSession $s -Destination d:\destinationFolder.

Comment: Thanks DAXaholic for your quick help.

Comment: Yeah bc your version does not support it?!

Comment: Sorry it was my bad I have update my Powershell version to 5. While creating session rather than give remote server computer name I have give local m/c name

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this today, but the root cause was the source folder I was copying from was empty. Once I put something in it to copy the -ToSession error went away.